# Logic behind sizeof() for character constants and function names

Tags: c++, c, sizeof

In *C* the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   char c='a';
   printf("%d %d",sizeof(c),sizeof('a'));
   return 0;
}
```

produces the result `1` and `4`? Please explain the logic?

Also, why does `sizeof(main())` result in `4` but `sizeof(main)` results in `1`:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

   printf("%d %d\n",sizeof(main), sizeof(main()));
   return 0;
}
```

And in *C++* why does `sizeof('a')` result in 1 but sizeof('av') results in 4?

Comment: In C++, the answer is `1 1`, in C it is `1 4`.

Comment: Note, the dups listed only cover half the question, so are not exact dups, this should be reopened.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Character constants* in *C* are of type *int*, although this is not the case in *C++*. From the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.4.4.4` *Character constants* paragraph *10* says (*emphasis mine*):

> An integer character constant **has type int**. The value of an integer character constant
>   containing a single character that maps to a single-byte execution character is the
>   numerical value of the representation of the mapped character interpreted as an integer.
>   The value of an integer character constant containing more than one character (e.g.,
>   'ab')[...]

from the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `2.14.3` *Character literals* paragraph *1* says (*emphasis mine*):

> [...]An **ordinary character literal** that contains a single c-char representable in the execution character set **has type char**,[...] An ordinary character literal that **contains more than one c-char is a multicharacter literal**. A multicharacter
>   literal, or an ordinary character literal containing a single c-char not representable in the execution character set, is conditionally-supported, **has type int**, and has an implementation-defined value.

So `av` is a *multicharacter literal* and will have size of *int*.

For the second part of the question, `sizeof(main)` is not valid code, although compiler may choose to still produce a result it will be *implementation defined*, from the draft C99 standard section `6.5.3.4` *The sizeof operator* paragraph *1* says:

> The sizeof operator shall not be applied to an expression that has function type or an
>   incomplete type, [...]

the draft C++ standard has similar wording and both `gcc` and `clang` warn about this code when using the `-pedantic` flag, with an error like this:

> warning: invalid application of 'sizeof' to a function type [-pedantic]

for `sizeof(main())` since `sizeof` is a compile time operator and does not evaluate it's arguments except in the case of variable length arrays the result is the size of the return type which is *int* in this case. For example we can see [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1cde26df053c923d):

```
long double func()
{
    return 1.0 ;
}
```

that `sizeof(func())` returns `16`.

**Note**

On your platform `sizeof(int)` is `4` but the size is *implementation defined*.

**Note 2**

Since the result of `sizeof` is *size_t* a more portable format specifier for `printf` would be `%zu`.

Answer (score 4):

Character constants are `int`s not `char`s. So `'a'` is stored in 4 bytes, than when stored in `c`, it is shortened to 1 to become a `char`.

Note that technically this size of `int`s are implementation dependent.

Comment: Why sizeof(main()) is 4 but sizeof(main) is 1? And thanx for the answer

Comment: That's the answer for C. In C++, character literals are `char`s, with size 1.